# Differences between these two ways to construct instance(Reflect and new)

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Parent.class(User and Element can be replaced by any classes)

```
public abstract class Parent {
    User user;

    public void InitUser() {
        Fileds f = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for(int i=0; i<f.length; i++) {
             f[i].set(this, new Element(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Child.class

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    Element e1;
    Element e2;

    public Child(User user) {
   　   super();
        this.user = user;
    }    

    public void doSomethingUsingE1AndE2() {
         // do something by using e1 and e2, invoking user's methods.
         user.perform(e1);
         user.perform(e2);

    }
}
```

In my Client.class, is there any differences between the following two ways to construct and use Child?

1.

```
public class Client() {
      User user = new User();
      Class childClass = Class.forName("com.xxx.Child");

      Constructor con = childClass .getConstructor(User.class);
      Object o = con.newInstance(user);
      Method initMethod = child.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "InitUser");
      initMethod.invoke(o);

      Method keyMethod = child.getMethod("doSomethingUsingE1AndE2");

      keyMethod.invoke(o);
}
```

2.

```
public class Client() {
      User user = new User();
      Child c = new Child(user);
      c.InitUser();
      c.doSomethingUsingE1AndE2();
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviourally, it's the same - for both of the approaches you'll have an instance of a class and you will invoke some instance methods.

The difference, however, is with the *use* of the compiler.

When you reflectively create an instance of a class, and reflectively call some method on this instance, the compiler does not *verify* that what you do is correct. Avoiding the compiler's help, you can end up with different errors at Runtime , like `NoSuchMethodError` (thrown when the method you desire to invoke doesn't exist or cannot be invoked), `InvocationTargetException` and other subclasses of [`ReflectiveOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException.html).

Following the non-reflective approach, is much safer - the compiler can verify that what you try to do is correct (are the methods accessible, are the parameters valid, etc.) and will throw you back a compiler error, before the program is started.

Note that Reflection is very useful sometimes, but

> ... if it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in creation. One in standard way (*new*) and another is [`Reflection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

But keep in mind that

> Reflection is powerful, but should not be used indiscriminately. If it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it. The following concerns should be kept in mind when accessing code via reflection.

- Performance Overhead
- Security Restrictions
- Exposure of Internals

Always try to use *new* way unless you have no other choices go for **Reflection**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.